# AWS policy generation facing syntax error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-policies

If I add this policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/stikbook-dev"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
    ]
}
```

I'm facing this error

> [Ln 4, Col 8Missing Resource: Add a Resource or NotResource element to the policy statement. Learn more
> Ln 6, Col 21 Unsupported Principal: The policy type IDENTITY_POLICY does not support the Principal element. Remove the Principal element. Learn more ]

What resource that I want to add? and "unsupported policy"?

Comment: Where do you want to add that policy? Having no resource and specifying a principal only makes sense when this is the assume role policy / trust relationship of a role.

Comment: I want to add it in custom policy which I generate because I can't able to access aws cli in local machine @luk2302 . I think , this is assume role policy

Answer (score 3):

You are generating a [trust policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/). But it seems that what you want is to create a [user managed or inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html). They have different purpose then trust policy. I guess your policy should look like the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

where `*` can be replaced by a specific ARN of [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) to be assumed.